# Short Date from jQuery Datepicker

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to extract a short date (`'m/d/yy'`) from jQuery Datepicker, but I have been unsuccessful. I've tried `formatDate`, `dateFormat`, `parseDate`, but still cannot get a short date format on the server side.

I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GentleMaN/zaexw5e7/1/) that I extracted and modified from one of the other threads on here.

It's my understanding that there's 2 different things we are dealing with in regards to jQuery UI Datepicker:

1. The date that is formatted & shown as the value of the input
2. The 'behind the scenes' value. I am trying to POST the date chosen
   as a short date, thus the format `Wed May 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400
   (Eastern Daylight Time)` doesn't work for me.

I understand that it's possible to convert the date to a string and format it that way, however I didn't know if it was possible within the jQuery UI library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery UI, you can do:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('m/d/yy', yourDate);     // where yourDate is the date variable
```

So in the jsFiddle this would become:

```
observable($.datepicker.formatDate('m/d/yy',$el.datepicker("getDate")));
```

See the demo (use datepicker to see the effect) for the results:

[**`> jsFiddle DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/ogL4mj0y/)

Comment: I was formatting it, but not binding the observable to the formatted value. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Invent-Animate: Always the little things that stump you for hours :)